# how I get title in component in React native

Tags: react-native

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

Im my component I call
 console.log(this.props.route);

Print this: 
Object {
  "key": "AddNew-b_MjpdpuB",
  "name": "AddNew",
  "params": undefined,
}

Answer (score 0):

Title is for navigation header, it is not passed to component itself. Use initialParams

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="MyScreen"
  component={MyComponent}
  initialParams={{ title: 'some title' }}
/>
```